# Assigning click event to multiple elements with different parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, each

I want to give a click event to many elements of the same type, but the function is depending on their position.

I want the click to place a div under the clicked element.

This is what I tried and it's not working.

```
$("#report-tabs .report-actions").each(function(){
    this.click(function(){
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        this.next().offset({left: offset.left});
    });
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you explain what you want to happen, rather than show us some code that doesn't achieve it?

Comment: I updated, also it's more question of syntax since I have a feeling that I use jquery wrong here

Comment: So when you click one of the selected elements, you want it to *create* a div and place it directly below it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#report-tabs .report-actions").on('click', function(){
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        $(this).next().css('left', offset.left + 'px');
});
```

Comment: is `this` referring to each element in the array separately ?

Comment: Yes ;) this is the principe of a scope